# The y value of my rectangle is not changing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am using the pygame module to make a simple game. Currently, I am trying to get a rectangle to move across my 500x500 screen, but it is only moving in x value (left and right).

Here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# Game Screen Dimensions
game_layout_length = 500
game_layout_width = 500

# Character Attributes
character_length = 10
character_width = 10
character_x = 0
character_y = 0

game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((game_layout_width, game_layout_length))

game_close = False
game_lost = False

while not game_close:

    while not game_lost:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_close = True
                game_lost = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    character_x -= 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    character_x += 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    character_y -= 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    character_y += 10

        pygame.draw.rect(game_screen, blue, [character_x, character_y, character_length, character_width])
        pygame.display.update()

print(f'{character_x, character_y}')
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

The line `print(f'{character_x, character_y}')` is a debug line, and it shows that the value of "character_y" is changing, so I'm stuck trying to find out where the problem is.

Comment: 1) No need to update the values which don't change. e.g. those " += 0 " lines.
2) Where were you putting the print line? Right before the draw call? Probably easier for others to help if you post complete code including the debug line.

Comment: Thanks, I will remove the values that don't change. And the print line is put right before the draw call. With that included, that's the entire code. I'm going to add more code after I fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moving down you need to increase the y and not decrease it and for moving up you need to decrease the y. Also you can fill the screen at each render to avoid the trailing rectangles.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# Game Screen Dimensions
game_layout_length = 500
game_layout_width = 500

# Character Attributes
character_length = 10
character_width = 10
character_x = 0
character_y = 0

game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((game_layout_width, game_layout_length))

game_close = False
game_lost = False

while not game_close:

    while not game_lost:

        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_close = True
                game_lost = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    character_x -= 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    character_x += 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    character_y += 10

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    character_y -= 10
        game_screen.fill(black)
        pygame.draw.rect(game_screen, blue, [character_x, character_y, character_length, character_width])
        pygame.display.update()

print(f'{character_x, character_y}')
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! It worked, but I'm just wondering why decreasing the y value makes it go up, and increasing it makes it go down. And why that same logic doesn't apply to the x value.

Comment: That's because of how the coordinate system works. The top left corner is (0, 0) [in (x, y) form] so increasing x will make it go right and increasing y makes it go down.